# How to get objects which are related one to one to the user model

Tags: python, django, rest, django-models, e-commerce

I'm creating an ecommerce website, currently loading the objects created by the customer to the cart template. My doubt is that how to get the customer which is related to the user by a one to one relationship?
the error is

```
Attribute error at /cart/
'User' has no object 'customer'
```

models.py :

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    price = models.FloatField()
    digital = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self):
        super().save()
        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300,300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    date_ordered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=False)
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

views:

```
def cart(request):

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
        items = order.orderitem_set.all()
    else:
        items = []
    context = {'items': items}
    return render(request, 'store/cart.html', context)
```

all i want to do is get the customer of the user.

Thank you! Your time and effort is appreciated!

Comment: I think you are following a youtube tutorial to make an ecommerce website.The problem is occuring because there is no customer object related to that model

Comment: You can solve it by: 1) Creating a customer for a user manually or using signals to create a customer whenever user is created

Comment: What you are using here foreing key not a one-to-one relationship . secondly you are doing like customer has a user. not user has a customer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use signals to create a customer whenever the user is created as follows:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import *

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def create_customer(sender,instance,created,**kwargs):
        if created:
            Customer.objects.create(user=instance)
    
    @receiver(post_save,sender=User)
    def update_customer(sender,instance,created,**kwargs):
        if created == False:
            instance.customer.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

The direct relation is customer.user but in your case You should use [backward relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects) : request.user.customer_set